# Why does this file give me syntax error: I give up in verilog program?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Why does this Verilog code give me the following syntax error?

> I give up in verilog program

This is my code:

```
module circuit_lee (a, b, c, d, e);
    input a, b, c, d, e;
    output y;
    wire w1, w2, w3, w4;
    or o1(w1, a, b);
    or o2(w4, w3, w2);
    and a1(w2, c, d);
    and a2(y, w4, e);
    not n1(w3, w1);
endmodule
```

```
`include "circuit_lee.v"

module circuit_lee_tb;
    reg a, b, c, d, e;
    wire y;

    circuit_lee add1(a, b, c, d, e, y);

    initial 
        begin
            $dumpfile("circuit_lee.vcd");
            $dumpvars(0,circuit_lee_tb);
            a = 0; b = 0; c = 0; d = 0; e = 0;
            #1
            a = 0; b = 0; c = 0; d = 1; e = 0;
            #1
            a = 0; b = 0; c = 1; d = 0; e = 0;
            #1
            a = 0; b = 0; c = 1; d = 1; e = 0;
            #1
            a = 0; b = 1; c = 0; d = 0; e = 0;
            #1
            a = 0; b = 1; c = 0; d = 1; e = 0;
            #1
            a = 0; b = 1; c = 1; d = 0; e = 0;
            #1
            a = 0; b = 1; c = 1; d = 1; e = 0;
            #1
            a = 1; b = 0; c = 0; d = 0; e = 0;
            #1
            a = 1; b = 0; c = 0; d = 1; e = 0;
            #1
            a = 1; b = 0; c = 1; d = 1; e = 0;
            #1
            a = 1; b = 1; c = 0; d = 0; e = 1;
            #1
            a = 1; b = 1; c = 0; d = 1; e = 1;
            #1
            a = 1; b = 1; c = 1; d = 0; e = 1;
            #1
            a = 1; b = 1; c = 1; d = 1; e = 1;
            #1
        end
endmodule
```

Comment: Verilog is just the language. That error is generated by a tool that deals with verilog. You need to tell us which tool!

Answer (score 5):

When your simulator does not give you a very helpful error message, you can try your code on other simulators on EDA playground.  For example, using the Cadence simulator, you get this message:

```
    output y;
           |
xmvlog: *E,NOPORT (testbench.sv,3|11): input/output/inout 'y' not declared in port list [12.3.2(IEEE)].
```

To fix that error, change:

```
module circuit_lee (a, b, c, d, e);
```

to:

```
module circuit_lee (a, b, c, d, e, y);
```

There is another syntax error after that.  All statements in Verilog must end with a semicolon.  Add it after the last `#1`:

```
        #1;
    end
```

Here is the complete code on [EDA playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/ZbNk), which compiles without errors.

Answer (score 4):

You declared `output y;` but it does not appear in your port list.

You are using very old Verilog-1995 port syntax which requires that you mention each port twice, sometimes 3 times. I strongly suggest using the Verilog-2001/SystemVerilog *ANSI-style* port list which would look like this:

```
module circuit_lee (
    input a, b, c, d, e,
    output y 
);
```